# OnValueChange called multiple times GWT

Tags: java, gwt, valuechangelistener

I'm using GWT 2.4 with Java & Mozilla FF 7. I have a **TextBox** & I've added a **ValueChangeHandler** to it. I've noticed that whenever I change the value of the **TextBox**, **OnValueChange** method is called multiple times on focus lost of the **TexBox**. My question is how many times **OnValueChange** method is called? Can I convert it to a single time call?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't actually add the `ValueChangeHandler` multiple times?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, Is there a way so that I can check whether any handler is already attached or not?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in every call to addValueChangeHandler and see how many times the debugger breaks there (alternatively, you could look inside the widget's `HandlerManager`)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, thanks for your reply. Post your 1st comment as your answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't actually add the `ValueChangeHandler` multiple times?